# Time Complexity of An Array That Sorts Only the Prefix Values

Tags: arrays, sorting, time-complexity

I am working on creating an algorithm of time complexity O(n) to sort an array by only switching the prefix values. For example, to sort the array `3,4,1,2` the procedure would look like:

```
3,4,1,2
4,3,1,2
2,1,3,4
3,1,2,4
2,1,3,4
1,2,3,4
```

Each time I bring the largest value of the array that is not in the right position to the front of the array then flip only up to the point that is not sorted to bring the largest value of that portion of the array to the end. Intuitively, I believe this would not be a time complexity of O(n) but I am not sure how to find the right the time complexity. My thought process so far is since there is an n+1 amount of operations being done on the array the constant would drop so it would have a time complexity of O(n). Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that there is an n+1 amount of operations being done on the array, however one of these operations itself has a time complexity of O(n) - this is the searching for the highest value which requires checking every element in the list.

Since checking for the highest value in the list happens on every loop, and the algorithm would have to loop n times, this results in a time complexity of at least O(n^2).

Comment: Is n+1 a constant value that can be dropped so the entire time complexity is O(n)?

Comment: n is referring to the number of elements in the list, so it isn't constant